# Optimize Tor Hidden Service

Tags: configuration

there is VERY little to find about optimizing a website which runs in the Tor network. Besides installing the Tor daemon, what can you do? Are there any tricks like connecting it to more relays than the standard config does? Anything?

Unfortunately I can't run my website over multiple servers. The only optimization I did so far is reducing the size of all images so the user doesn't have to download so much. Sites like -for example- Grams load really quick. They must have done something to achieve that.

PS: I'm using nginx, it's optimized. Server is strong. The bottleneck is the connection to the tor network. I'm aware that it will never be as fast as in the clearnet, but i'm sure somehow I could do better.

Comment: You can take a look at the performance tuning guide in [the docs](https://gitweb.torproject.org/tor.git/blob/HEAD:/doc/TUNING)

Comment: Sam, i believe the document you linked is just helpful if you run a tor relay yourself, therefore not answering my question at all.

Comment: The things in that document should help with a hidden service as well (not quite to the extent as with relays, but if you have a high volume server it should still help).

Comment: no it's not like we're running facebook :) it's a rather small site with a few hundred visitors a day. thats why i don't think the ulimit parameter could help in any way ; quote: "for a busy Tor relay"

Answer (score 0):

well, it may make sense to limit the data size to 512 bytes, as the tor/onion net seems to be able to take that payload without fragmentation: [TOR and Obfsproxy packet size](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/9127/tor-and-obfsproxy-packet-size)

ie in case nginx is used, i'd try to set `[sndbuf=size]` in the listen directive http://nginx.org/en/docs/stream/ngx_stream_core_module.html#listen. not sure if  `[rcvbuf=size]` would help as well …

Comment: Each relay{data} cell can have a maximum payload of 498 bytes: https://gitweb.torproject.org/torspec.git/tree/tor-spec.txt#n1576